# How are the absolute value signs introduced when using fractional exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know that by definition,

$$ \sqrt{x^2}=\left | x \right | \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$

But what if I use this definition:

$$ \sqrt[q]{x^p}=x^\frac{p}{q} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R} \quad \forall p, q \in \mathbb{Z} \quad q\neq 0$$

on $ \sqrt{x^2} $?

Then I'll get

$$ \sqrt{x^2}=x^\frac{2}{2}=x $$

Which is obvously **NOT** true, since the solution should be $\pm x$

Comment: First of all, $\sqrt{x^2} \neq \pm x$. Why? Well, first of all, for $\sqrt{\cdot}$ to be a function, it has to only have one output. When we solve the equation $x^2 = 1$, we write $x = \pm 1$ because both $(-1)^2$ and $1^2$ equal $1$. It does not mean, however, that $\sqrt{x^2}$ gives two values.

Comment: @Clarinetist You meant that for the last sentence of mine, right? I think I might have confused $\left | x \right |$ with $\pm x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "definition" is

$$ \sqrt[q]{x^p}=x^\frac p q  \quad \forall x \in \color{red}{\Bbb R^+} \quad \forall p, q \in \Bbb Z  \quad q\neq 0$$

not for all $x \in \Bbb R$. When $x < 0$, there is no single definition of the value that works for all $p$ and $q$.

Comment: Oh stupid me, I should have realised that, since if e.g. $x=-1$ and $p=1$ $q=2$ then the root is $ \sqrt{-1} $ which is undefined on $\mathbb{R}$.